# How to highly recommend a user to launch an app when the app is not up?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have the need to have an application always active in windows phone 8. All users have to use this application. More precisely, all users will have a background agent inside this application which will receive and send informations.
*Note : I'm talking here about a private application use by a limited number of users.*

During my research, I became aware that i couldn't paramater my application in order to launch it at startup. This isn't possible with Windows phone 8. So, i start looking for others options.

In my understanding, the only way to do that in the Microsoft way is to use the notifications. If the phone don't have the application launched, a notification is send periodically to invite the user to launch the application.

**My question, did I miss some functionnalites in Windows Phone 8 whiches propose the same functionnality in a better way ?**

Thank you very much

Comment: I think notification is your best bet, and keep in mind user can turn off notification. The principle is user decides which to launch, not the developer.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I have to keep in mind the fact that the user can turn off the notification.